# MyInfinity thermostat dropping connection with Carrier server

Tags: thermostat, wifi, carrier

My MyInfinity thermostat keeps randomly dropping connection carrier server. Wifi connectivity is stable (Arris TG1682g modem). Thermostat panel shows not connected to www.api.ing.carrier.com

Thermostat Model number: systxccitc01-b
Software version: 131625-01.32

Any ideas on what may be causing this and how to fix this? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: It appears local WiFi is staying connected but the internet connection between you and the server has issues.

Comment: except thermostat, all other device has no problem. i haven't noticed any issues connecting to other websites from phone, etc.

Comment: @Bill can you connect to www.api.ing.carrier.com using your web browser, or ping it from a command prompt for that matter?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel `ping` shows `Request timeout for icmp_seq 0` and going through the browser gives `403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.` So my guess is carrier server is blocking those connections. But i can connect to it from thermostat. It just randomly drops connection intermittently.

Comment: Normal web browsing doesn’t create persistent connections, a better indicator might be streaming video, but even that’s problematic because it’s designed to buffer for splotchy connections.  Testing ping and speed *might* be an indicator of internet connection issues as well.  There is no one sure method.  From what we see in the picture tho, it’s seems local WiFi isn’t the issue.  The problem is upstream and most problematic in that regard is usually always the segment from house to isp.

Comment: is it supposed to stay connected continuously? .... how long does it stay disconnected? .... what is the reason for the connection?

Comment: It has been staying connected for 4 minutes, disconnected for 2 minutes. The cycle continues. It is supposed to stay connected all the time. Because of this I can’t access the thermostat from app on mobile or web

Comment: If the problem is from isp from house, wouldn’t all internet connectivity have issues? Why will only drop connections happen for thermostat. I haven’t noticed any internet connectivity issues from any appliance. What can I do to fix this or prove this to my internet provider?

Comment: Persistent connections are different than normal web browsing.  If you have access to a modem interface page that shows correctable and uncorrectable packet errors, [like this](https://imgur.com/a/vHfHp0V).  I bet you have a bunch of uncorrectable packet errors.   Modern browsers and high speed connections do a good job of masking the problem from the user, you’re not so lucky with persistent connections.  Your modem login might be at http://192.168.100.1 with user: admin and password either admin or password if not those search dslreports.com for your modem and isp’s defaults.

Comment: i logged in the router portal, but i don't see any packet errors.

Comment: Do you not see the section with correctable and uncorrectable counts at all, or do you see it telling you “uncorrectable: 0”   If you actually see “uncorrectable: 0” then this isn’t the problem, if on the other hand you aren’t finding the section that lists uncorrectables (also known as dropped packets) then don’t rule this out yet.  Is your modem/router one device?  Is it cable, fiber or dsl?

Comment: I have Xfinity. I see “correctable and uncorrectable codeward” under CM error codeword section. Under there, there are no uncorrectable, that is count zero. I don’t have a packet loss section. If you know how to find packet loss for Xfinity router I can give you that information. Modem/router is one device and I believe Xfinity is cable. Thanks for your help

Comment: If uncorrectables is zero, then I have no further suggestions.  You have a different problem than I had (mine involved a weather station tho, not a thermostat but same type of connection to server dropping)

Comment: Just for my curiosity, what did you do to fix the problem?

Comment: Argued with Comcast for weeks and two tech visits, finally complained on twitter which got me to a different part of customer service that treated me like royalty and sent a special tech that ultimately told me the problem was affecting my entire neighborhood and they replaced an amplifier in my next door neighbors back yard.  All the while, normal web browsing and speed were fine, persistent connections weren’t fine tho due to the uncorrectable/dropped packets.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue with the Carrier thermostat shown in the picture.  Exact same symptoms - connected to the home network, but would not stay connected to the Carrier network, could not link to weather forecasts, etc. However, had an older Carrier thermostat upstairs (on the same network) and it was working fine. Noted that the DNS settings on the troublesome thermostat looked odd so compared with the DNS settings on the working thermostat.  They didn't match so I entered the settings from the working thermostat into the troublesome thermostat.  Waited about 15-20 minutes for the new DNS settings to propagate and now it is working fine.  Not sure how it lost the DNS settings in the first place nor why they didn't get reloaded properly.

Comment: So, you expect @Bill to copy the DNS settings from *your* old thermostat? This is a nice anectode, but not useful for other readers.

Comment: @donald can you please post your dns settings?

Comment: I checked my dns settings. They are 75.75.75.75 and 75.75.76.76 which seems valid Comcast dns servers. @Donald, can you please tell exactly where you changed and what?

Comment: Based on a quick search, I see Comcast dns servers have reported to be dropping connections. I’m switching to use google’s dns. Let’s see how that goes. Will update tomorrow

Comment: Changing DNS didn’t fix it. Moreover when  disconnecting and reconnecting to WiFi, the DNS settings got overwritten